# How to set dynamic value in variable or connect two variable Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an array with a variable `ecoveneer_magma_oak` that I want to change by pressing a button.
When I change the variable in console, everything is good but I don't see my value on the page.

PS: I am a beginner in Vue.

Here is my code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <swiper-slide
      v-for="door in doors"
      :key="door.id"
      class="card"
      :door="doors"
    ></swiper-slide>
    <div class="modelName">{{ door.model }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ecoveneer_magma_oak: 'Дуб Магма',
      doors: [
        {
          image: '1.jpg',
          model: '018 BG',
          ecoveneer_magma_oak: 'Дуб Бордо',
          decor: this.ecoveneer_magma_oak,
          id: '1',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeLange(lang) {
      this.ecoveneer_magma_oak = 'Ecoveneer Magma Oak'
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not post irrelevant code images that do not bring anything relevant to your question. Please use `ESlint` + `Prettier` for your Nuxt project to remove the bare errors that your editor can give you. If you're speaking about a button, please link it in the initial question. I've edited your question, please review my changes and double check that this is fine with you. Then, I highly recommend you using some basic debugging tools and trying to understand where the error comes from thanks to the available tools. Some details can be found here: https://nn21.kissu.io/13

Comment: Hi, what is that? Please edit your initial question..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have spend 2 work days for find answer but nothing Now I declare variable not in data then I change variable and refresh DOM but variable "decor" not changing

```
var ecoveneer_magma_oak= 'Дуб Бордо'
      export default {
        data() {
    doors: [
        {
          image:"1.jpg",
          model:"018 BG",
          decor: ecoveneer_magma_oak,
          id:"1"
        }],
    methods: {
      changeLange(lang){    
          if(lang==='RU'){
             this.renderComponent = false;
            this.$nextTick(() => {
              // Add the component back in
              this.renderComponent = true;
            });
          
          ecoveneer_magma_oak="Ecoveneer Magma Oak"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your issue or your updated question?